# How can I access elements (div ClassNames) in a Javascript array, and change their opacity?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is generated by searching for elements by ClassName:

```
var tempNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("grids");
```

How can I access each element (divs, basically) and change their opacity? I have tried this:

```
tempNodeList[b].style.opacity = 0
```

Where "b" is a variable in a for-in loop. However, I cannot seem to get to the objects to affect their opacity/other properties.

EDIT:
I did convert the HTML Collection/NodeList to an array. New array is called allBoxes.
But I just can't seem to access an element with:

```
allBoxes[1].style.opacity
```

Here is my function (still a work in progress). The commented out lines at the end are what I'm using to try to run a fade loop on the items in the array.

```
box01.addEventListener("mouseenter", fadeOutBoxes);
```

box02.addEventListener("mouseenter", fadeOutBoxes);

function fadeOutBoxes(e) {

```
var thisBox = e.target.id;

var grid = thisBox.slice(0, 4);
var tempBoxNum = thisBox.slice(4);
var boxNum = ("0" + tempBoxNum).slice(-2);
var gridBoxNum = grid.concat(boxNum);

console.log("grid = " + grid);
console.log("tempBoxNum = " + tempBoxNum);
console.log("boxNum = " + boxNum);
console.log("gridBoxNum = " + gridBoxNum);

///// for in enumerative testing //////////////////////
var tempNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("grids"); /// THIS CREATES AN HTML COLLECTION-NOT AN ARRAY
console.log(tempNodeList.valueOf()); //for testing - just lists out the array elements
var allBoxes = Array.from(tempNodeList); /// CONVERT THE HTML COLLECTION TO AN ARRAY
    console.log(allBoxes);

for (var b in allBoxes) {
    console.log(allBoxes[b].id);

        //if (allBoxes[b].id === "grid01") { // works with specified name
        if (allBoxes[b].id === gridBoxNum) { // trying with programmatically generated name


            //remove THIS BOX from array
            allBoxes.splice(b, 1);
        }

    ////// run fades on the newly trimmed array of gridBoxes
    var op = 1; // intial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op <= 0.1){
        clearInterval(timer);   
    }
    //e.target.style.opacity = op; // HOLD - original opacity fade command
    //console.log("e.target.style.opacity: " + e.target);
    //allBoxes[1].style.opacity = op;
    op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 20);
}
```

}

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. If you use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) this is pretty easy. Currently, it's not clear why that code is not working.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - added my function (work in progress). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop like below.

```js
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (let i of element) {
  i.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the object by creating an array with Object.values. This will give the array of all the elements and you can change the style one by one in the loop

```js
var tempNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("grids");
Object.values(tempNodeList).forEach(e=>e.style.opacity = 0)
```

```html
<div class="grids">a</div><div class="grids">b</div><div class="grids">c</div><div class="grids">d</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, is mapping the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by `getElementsByClassName()` to an array using the spread operator. Note that an HTMLCollection is not an array:

> The **HTMLCollection** interface represents a **generic collection** (array-like object similar to arguments) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list.

**Example: (Updated to use fade-out effect)**

```js
var tempNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("grids");

var op = 1;

var timer = setInterval(() =>
{
    op -= 0.1;
    [...tempNodeList].forEach(x => x.style.opacity = op);

    if (op <= 0.1)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("Stop fadeOut effect!");
    }
}, 150);
```

```html
<div class="grids" style="background:red;">RED</div>
<div class="grids" style="background:blue;">BLUE</div>
<div class="grids" style="background:yellow;">YELLOW</div>
```

But you can actually do the same with a simple `for` loop:

```js
var tempNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("grids");

var op = 1;
var timer = setInterval(() =>
{
    op -= 0.1;

    for (let i = 0; i < tempNodeList.length; i++)
    {
        tempNodeList[i].style.opacity = op;
    }
    
    if (op <= 0.1)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("Stop fadeOut effect;");
    }
}, 150);
```

```html
<div class="grids" style="background:red;">RED</div>
<div class="grids" style="background:blue;">BLUE</div>
<div class="grids" style="background:yellow;">YELLOW</div>
```

Comment: The second set of code is exactly what the OP says they are using, with an unexplained  `setTimeout` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.from(tempNodeList).forEach(
    a => a.style.opacity = 0
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert array like Object to `array` and then loop

```js
function changeOpacity(){
   var tempNodeList =      document.getElementsByClassName("grids");
    Array.from(tempNodeList).forEach(elm => {
      elm.style.opacity = 0;
    })
}
```

```css
.grids{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grids"></div>
<div class="grids"></div>
<div class="grids"></div>
<div class="grids"></div>
<div class="grids"></div>
<div class="grids"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
```